# Get gradient with respect to an activation in Keras

Tags: keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I can get gradient of loss w.r.t input tensor by explicitly adding a watch to my input like below:

```
t = tf.keras.Input(shape=(5))
x = tf.sin(t)
y = tf.cos(t)
z = x + y
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=t, outputs=z)
loss_fn = tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError()

with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tape:    
    data_x = tf.random.normal([5])
    data_y = tf.random.normal([5])
    tape.watch(data_x)
    y_pred = model(data_x)
    loss = loss_fn(data_y, y_pred)

dL_dt = tape.gradient(loss, [data_x])
```

How can I do the same thing for a specific layer's output? Adding a watch by doing something like `tape.watch(model.layers[1].output)` does not work:

```
~/miniconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/backprop.py in watch(self, tensor)
    903     for t in nest.flatten(tensor, expand_composites=True):
    904       if not (_pywrap_utils.IsTensor(t) or _pywrap_utils.IsVariable(t)):
--> 905         raise ValueError("Passed in object of type {}, not tf.Tensor".format(
    906             type(t)))
    907       if not backprop_util.IsTrainable(t):

ValueError: Passed in object of type <class 'tensorflow.python.keras.engine.keras_tensor.KerasTensor'>, not tf.Tensor
```

**Update**: If I define my Model such that it always returns my activation of interest as an output (`model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=t, outputs=[z, x])`) then I can later use that output for computing gradients but Keras can't be this bad. There must be a much easier way.

Comment: the simplest way is to define sub_model = Model(inputs=model.input, outputs=model.layers[1].output) and call it inside the GradientTape

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar error, the answer in your case is somehow straightforward. just define a layer and use your activation as its activation. here is a working sample on tf2

```
t = tf.keras.Input(shape=(1,))
x = keras.layers.Dense(2, input_dim=1, activation=tf.sin, use_bias=True)(t)
y = keras.layers.Dense(1, input_dim=1, activation=tf.cos, use_bias=True)(t)
z = x + y
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=t, outputs=z)
loss_fn = tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError()

with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tape:    
    data_x = tf.random.normal([1])
    data_y = tf.random.normal([1])
    tape.watch(data_x)
    y_pred = model(data_x)
    loss = loss_fn(data_y, y_pred)

dL_dt = tape.gradient(loss, [data_x])
```